# Compiler Error: CS1026: ) expected

Tags: c#

When I try to compile my code the compiler gives me this error:

> CS1026: ) expected

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(myFile.InputStream)))
{
    List<BlogPosts> blogPosts = new List<BlogPosts>();
    blogPosts = reader.ReadContentAsAsync(List List<BlogPosts>);
}
```

I don't seem to be missing a closing parentheses anywhere in my code. So where's the error?

Comment: `List List<BlogPosts`?

Comment: `.ReadContentAsAsync(List List<BlogPosts>)` ?

Comment: but you're confusing the compiler with `ReadContentAsAsync(List List<BlogPosts>);`

Comment: this one `List List<BlogPosts>);`

Comment: `blogPosts = reader.ReadContentAsAsync(typeof (List<BlogPosts>));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you got to change your:

```
blogPosts = reader.ReadContentAsAsync(List List<BlogPosts>);
```

into:

```
blogPosts = reader.ReadContentAsAsync(typeof(List<BlogPosts>), null); //change null to any necessary IXmlNamespaceResolver
```

[XmlReader.ReadContentAsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasasync(v=vs.110).aspx) receives `Type` as input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the following line is invalid

```
ReadContentAsAsync(List List<BlogPosts>);
```

Check the parameters.

---

To please those who think this is not a sufficiently detailed answer:

The `ReadContentAsAsync` method requires two parameters: the expected return type and a namespace resolver. You're just passing something that's not valid syntactically.

Probably you want this:

```
blogPosts = reader.ReadContentAsAsync(typeof(List<BlogPosts>), null);
```

as `blogPosts` is of type `List<BlogPosts>`. In case you need to resolve namespaces as well, pass a namespace resolver instead of `null` for the second parameter.

Comment: This is not an answer, but merely a comment. you don't provide any solution to the problem

Comment: I tend to disagree with you here, as the question is "why am I getting Compiler Error xyz. Where's the error?" - the answer is: The syntax is invalid. But I'm going to edit the answer anyway.